# Puppeteer frame.type is only typing the first character of input

Tags: node.js, iframe, puppeteer

So, I've got an iFrame built with react.js and ember.js - I think.  Truth is I'm just trying to automate some testing for it.  I'm using puppeteer.js and when I go to type in the input, only the first character is being typed.

```
const frameHandle = await page.$('iframe[id="sso-iframe"]');
const frame = await frameHandle.contentFrame();
let hotDamn='Hot Damn';
await frame.type('[data-foobar="true"]', hotDamn, { delay: 100 });
```

In the above, only the letter "H' gets typed.   I'm not sure why.  Any ideas?

---

After further tomfoolery...and I tried

```
const frameHandle = await page.$('iframe[id="sso-iframe"]');
const frame = await frameHandle.contentFrame();
let hotDamn='Hot Damn';
await frame.type('[data-foobar="true"]', hotDamn, { delay: 100 }); 
await frame.type('[data-foobar="true"]', hotDamn, { delay: 100 });
await frame.type('[data-foobar="true"]', hotDamn, { delay: 100 });
```

and what gets typed is "HHot DamnHot Damn".   Whaaaaa?

Answer (score 3):

Actually I figured out my problem - well a solution.   I had to click before typing.

```
await frame.click('[data-foobar="true"]'); 
await frame.type('[data-foobar="true"]', hotDamn, { delay: 100 });
```

Comment: Worked in my case

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you run it in headless or headfull, but I can't reproduce it. Below is simplest example possible, I believe:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="test.html" id="sso-iframe"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span>Input</span><input data-foobar="true" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js** - node.js express application, for simplicity puppeteer is done here as well:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


function serve() {
    app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening on port 3000'));

    const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");


    (async () => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
          headless: false,
        });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto("http://localhost:8000");
        const frameHandle = await page.$('iframe[id="sso-iframe"]');
        const frame = await frameHandle.contentFrame();
        let hotDamn='Hot Damn';
        await frame.type('[data-foobar="true"]', hotDamn, { delay: 100 });
        await frame.type('[data-foobar="true"]', hotDamn, { delay: 100 });
        await frame.type('[data-foobar="true"]', hotDamn, { delay: 100 });

    })();
}

serve();
```

**I can see "Hot DamnHot DamnHot Damn" being typed correctly.** Could you share how do you actually `assert` the value?

Comment: Actually I figured out my problem - well a solution.   I had to click before typing.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've figured out that the first typed char isn't typed, just the following ones. Clicking the field didn't help.

So it turned out that I had to type one character with `delay: 100` inside the field. This char didn't actually appear on the field - it just paved the way for the following typed chars (which needn't be delayed).

This is the code that works for me (it's about payment `iframe` inside my website, and I was trying to enter card number):

```
await page.waitForSelector("iframe");
const elementHandle = await page.$('div#payment-frame iframe');
const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
await frame.waitForSelector('#input-card');
const cardNo = await frame.$('#input-card');
await cardNo.type('0', { delay: 100 });
await cardNo.type('4580458045804580');
```